# What is the correct way to specify weights in bigglm with SQLite as backend database?

Tags: r

How do you specify weights in bigglm?

I tried the following code

```
 m <- bigglm(f3~f1+f2,data=con,tablename="t",weights=~weight,chunksize= 5000,family =binomial())
```

where f3 and f1 and f2 and weight are fields in SQLite database. But it fails with following error message.

```
Error in coef.bigqr(object$qr) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
```

Running

```
 m <- bigglm(f3~f1+f2,data=con,tablename="t",chunksize= 5000,family =binomial())
```

yields a model with no error message.

I tried running

```
    dbListFields(con, "t")
```

and weight was one of the variables listed. Although there is another variable called weight:1 being list in the output.

Comment: I tried with a toy data set and it works. Can you do `dbListFields(con, "t")`

Comment: You don't give us enough information to help. What is the error message ? can you list the column in your SQLite table (may be the name is not "weight").

Comment: It's just that weight was not defined as num in SQLite just need to convert it that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the weight is a numeric type if not then try

```
weight=~as.numeric(weight)
```